# Django model class decorator

Tags: python, django

I have a need to track changes on Django model instances. I'm aware of solutions like django-reversion but they are overkill for my cause.

I had the idea to create a parameterized class decorator to fit this purpose. The arguments are the field names and a callback function. Here is the code I have at this time:

```
def audit_fields(fields, callback_fx):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__old_init(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__old_state = self.__get_state_helper()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_state = self.__get_state_helper()

        for k,v in new_state.items():
            if (self.__old_state[k] != v):
                callback_fx(self, k, self.__old_state[k], v)

        val = self.__old_save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__old_state = self.__get_state_helper()
        return val

    def __get_state_helper(self):
        # make a list of field/values.
        state_dict = dict()
        for k,v in [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in self._meta.fields if field.name in fields]:
            state_dict[k] = v
        return state_dict

    def fx(clazz):
        # Stash originals
        clazz.__old_init = clazz.__init__
        clazz.__old_save = clazz.save

        # Override (and add helper)
        clazz.__init__ = __init__
        clazz.__get_state_helper = __get_state_helper
        clazz.save = save
        return clazz

    return fx
```

And use it as follows (only relevant part):

```
@audit_fields(["status"], fx)
class Order(models.Model):
    BASKET = "BASKET"
    OPEN = "OPEN"
    PAID = "PAID"
    SHIPPED = "SHIPPED"
    CANCELED = "CANCELED"
    ORDER_STATES = ( (BASKET, 'BASKET'),
                 (OPEN, 'OPEN'),
                 (PAID, 'PAID'),
                 (SHIPPED, 'SHIPPED'),
                 (CANCELED, 'CANCELED') )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=ORDER_STATES, default=BASKET)
```

And test on the Django shell with:

```
from store.models import Order
o=Order()
o.status=Order.OPEN
o.save()
```

The error I receive then is:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Order'
```

The full stacktrace is here: https://gist.github.com/4020212

Thanks in advance and let me know if you would need more info!

**EDIT:** Question answered by randomhuman, code edited and usable as shown!

Comment: it is very confusing that both your callback and internal function are named `fx`.

Comment: Just a minor nit. The naming convention for class so as not to conflict with the keyword is to name a variable holding a type "klass". Don't know if it's formal but I've seen code like that in many frameworks in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly pass a reference to *self* on this line:

```
val = self.__old_save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

It is a method being called on an object reference. Passing it explicitly in this way is causing it to be seen as one of the other parameters of the save method, one which is expected to be a string or a number.

Comment: Indeed randomhuman, changed this but still the same error... So the question remains unanswered :(

Comment: The first line of the new `__init__` has the same problem, though I would have thought the problem related to the line I mentioned originally. Is the stack trace exactly the same as previously?

Comment: Apparently reimporting the file on the Python shell isn't a full refresh... was getting late last night :-) Thanks for the help randomhuman!

Comment: Yeah, if you just did a second import then it wouldn't: when you import a module it checks to see if it has been imported previously, and if it has nothing is done. You'd have to take extraordinary measures to perform a "re-import". Glad you got it going anyway!